# Excel merge rows by ID

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got a set of columns like this in excel:

```
ID                                      sizeAndColourAndSku_Value
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Select size
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Extra Small - Available (only 1 left)
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Small - Available (only 2 left)
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Medium - Available (only 2 left)
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9    Large - Available (only 1 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    Select size
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    6 - Available (only 2 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    8 - Available (only 4 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    10 - Available (only 6 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    12 - Available (only 6 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    14 - Available (only 4 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    16 - Available (only 2 left)
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95    Select size
```

I need to combine merge them by their ID so the results become like this:

```
2ff0d3d7-8c18-4386-83be-1b2485fb4ea9   Extra Small  Small  Medium  Large
4697ce05-2e50-4e67-85d5-ad733e15ae95   6      8      10     12      14
```

I read here that the quickest and easiest way to do this is with a pivot table in excel

http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=235727

However I'm using excel 2010 and the method they've provided doesn't really work, anyone able to help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Asked as well on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18126815/1578604). Do you have a maximum of sizes for each ID?

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean "maximum of sizes for each ID"?

Comment: So far, there is "Extra Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large" for the first item, "6", "8", "10", "12", "14" and "16" for the second item. So, item 1 has 4 sizes, item 2 has 5 sizes. Is that the maximum sizes possible? Is there an item with, say, 100 different sizes?

Comment: umm not sure, the size column values can be pretty dynamic. It's not supplied by me, but rather by the client so I really have no idea how big it can go. But since it's for clothes I'm assuming not to 100

Comment: Hmm, I don't know easy ways, and there'll probably be a lot of formulas, some helpers and some for the final results. I assume that the data is currently in columns A and B. Try running `=IF(B2=$B$2,0,C1+1)` in column C as from row 2 (row 1 contains headers, right?) till the end. Put a filter and check the largest number.

Comment: right now its just test data so the largest number is 6, but its more realistic that some clothes sizes might go up to 12

Comment: Hmm, what I would suggest right now would be [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/Clothes%20sample.xlsx) (This is an xlsx workbook created in Ex2007). You've got the formulae inside, and provides for up to 12 different sizes per product. You can then copy/paste the data into a fresh sheet and remove the blank rows.

Comment: thanks a lot for the workbook. What if the sizes go over 12, is there somewhere I can modify to change this number?

Comment: I found this article http://dposorio.com/blog/4/how-to-merge-data-in-excel-or-calc-spreadsheet/  and it seems to do what I need but only with columns. I need it to work with rows, would you have any suggestions how I can modify their solution for my case?

Comment: I updated the excel sheet so you can always add more columns to the right and drag the formula across and below, but you must then properly enumerate the column numbers. That's where the column C helps in identifying on what column you should stop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're looking for, but I think you just want these rows aggregated by ID with the text to the left of the hyphen from each row entered in a new column to the right of the ID.

Two steps:

1. Copy the ID column to where you want your new merged table. Apply `Remove Duplicates` (on the Data ribbon) to the copied column. This will give you your column of unique IDs.
2. Select the first blank cell to the right of the first ID in your new table. Paste the following formula into the formula bar and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter it as an array formula.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(INDEX($B$1:$B$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$12=$F1,ROW($B$1:$B$12)),COLUMN(A1))),FIND(" - ",INDEX($B$1:$B$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$12=$F1,ROW($B$1:$B$12)),COLUMN(A1))))-1),"")
```

Here `A1:A12` is the ID column in the original data, and `B1:B12` are values. `F1` is the location of the first ID in the new merged table. Adjust these ranges as necessary to match your data.

Finally fill over and down as far as you need to.

[image]

Comment: Okay I've completed the remove duplicates part, I've placed the new column of ID's at F1 to avoid confusion. I've applied the formula but I'm getting a blank cell afterwards

Comment: @jc.yin Does your original data start in Row 1? If not, make the first argument of the `INDEX` functions start at row 1 (and extend to the last item in your data). This could fix the problem.

Comment: Yea it does, now it just gives in columnG1 the exact same value as columnB1, here's a link to my test file [link](http://db.tt/kMyNyxFr)

Comment: You didn't successfully enter the formula as an *array formula*. Double click `G1` and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. You'll see the formula will be wrapped in curly brackets if you do this successfully, e.g. `{=IFERROR(...)}`. Once you've done that, fill over and down. Note, you have to do array entry like this anytime you edit the formula. Also note, The first column will be blank because of the "Select Size" entries with no hyphens. This column can be removed afterward if you want.

Comment: I did Ctrl+Shift+Enter and the formula was surrounded with curly brackets. However the cell remains empty. When I click the formula bar, the curly brackets disappear and then the cell has a value again, but only one.

Comment: It *should* be blank. If it's blank, fill the formula down and over.

Comment: Please take a [look](http://db.tt/kMyNyxFr) at the new file, I've filled down and over with the curly bracketed formula yet still the cells are blank

Comment: You didn't update the formula to match your data and you didn't fill over. Updated formula for your workbook: `=IFERROR(LEFT(INDEX($B$1:$B$95,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$95=$F1,ROW($B$1:$B$95)),COLUMN(A1))),FIND(" - ",INDEX($B$1:$B$95,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$95=$F1,ROW($B$1:$B$95)),COLUMN(A1))))-1),"")`. Enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter then fill down AND over.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but what does down and over mean? I know drag down by cell but over?

Comment: Also I'm getting an error when I Ctrl+Shift+Enter the formula in cell G1. The error is: "The formula you typed contains errors"

Comment: "Fill over" = fill to the right.  I've explained more than enough for you to get this to work -- I even got it to work in the sample workbook you provided. So, if you're still having problems I suggest reading through the answer and comments again.